# volatile in c++: should I define a variable which may changes by several thread as volatile?

Tags: c++, multithreading, volatile

I have a variable which is shared between several threads (assuming suitable sync method is in place).

Should I define the variable as volatile?

The reason that I am asking is: Any of the following can be the answer:

yes: Since the variable can be change by a thread and other thread should be aware of it.

no: Since compiler can understand that a value for a variable is on CPU memory and it doesn't matter which thread wants to read it, compiler would take care of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have suitable synchronization in place, then there is no need for `volatile`.

If you do not have suitable synchronization in place, then `volatile` does not supply suitable synchronization, although in some C++ implementations it might appear to help to a greater or lesser extent.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should only use `volatile` if a library API requires it (e.g. atomic operations on Windows).

There are cases in very low level programming dealing with hardware where `volatile` can be required.

Comment: I can understand why to use it in low level programming (memory mapped IO), but should I use it in library API? Any sample or reference?

Comment: @mans: You should not use when you design your own API's.

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` is (nearly) useless for a multithreaded application programming. It was intended for use when interfacing with memory-mapped hardware. Although C++ Standard is silent about `volatile` in terms of Acquire or Release semantics on variables some specific platforms however do add additional functionality or restrictions to what `volatile` does. For example, in Windows 2010 (at least) Acquire and Release semantics do apply to certain operations on `volatile` variables:

> Microsoft Specific
>
> Objects declared as volatile are not used in certain optimizations
>   because their values can change at any time. The system always reads
>   the current value of a volatile object at the point it is requested,
>   even if a previous instruction asked for a value from the same object.
>   Also, the value of the object is written immediately on assignment.
>   When optimizing, the compiler must maintain ordering among references
>   to volatile objects as well as references to other global objects. In
>   particular,
>
> A write to a volatile object (volatile write) has Release semantics; a
>   reference to a global or static object that occurs before a write to a
>   volatile object in the instruction sequence will occur before that
>   volatile write in the compiled binary.
>
> A read of a volatile object (volatile read) has Acquire semantics; a
>   reference to a global or static object that occurs after a read of
>   volatile memory in the instruction sequence will occur after that
>   volatile read in the compiled binary.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx